# Need help to decide between the type of spellchecker to use in solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, spell-checking, autosuggest, solrcloud

I have a list of cities on mysql db which is hooked onto a UI for autocompletion purposes. I am currently using solr-5.3.0. Data import is happening through scheduled delta imports. I have the following questions:

1. I want to implement spell checker to this feature. I tried using:

   1. DirectSolrSpellChecker
   2. IndexBasedSpellChecker
   3. FileBasedSpellChecker

   Out of these 3 only FileBasedSpellChecker is able to give
   suggestions that solely exists on db. For eg, while searching
   **cologne** I've got results like

   ```
       {
     "responseHeader":{
       "status":0,
       "QTime":4,
       "params":{
         "q":"searchfield:kolakata",
         "indent":"true",
         "spellcheck":"true",
         "wt":"json"}},
     "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
     },
     "spellcheck":{
   "suggestions":[
     "cologne",{
       "numFound":4,
       "startOffset":12,
       "endOffset":19,
       "suggestion":["Cologne",
         "Bologna",
         "Cogne",
         "Bastogne"]}],
   "collations":[
     "collation","searchfield:Cologne"]}}
   ```

   These cities are pretty accurate and exists in db/file.

   But when I use other 2 I got results like

   ```
     {
     "responseHeader":{
       "status":0,
       "QTime":4,
       "params":{
         "q":"searchfield:kolakata",
         "indent":"true",
         "spellcheck":"true",
         "wt":"json"}},
     "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
     },
     "spellcheck":{
   "suggestions":[
     "cologne",{
       "numFound":4,
       "startOffset":12,
       "endOffset":19,
       "suggestion":["Cologne",
         "Cologn",
         "Colognei"]}],
   "collations":[
     "collation","searchfield:Cologne"]}}
   ```

   These cities who are not present in my db.

   Though FileBasedSpellChecker is giving satisfactory results, but I
   am a little apprehensive in using them because, I would need to keep
   updating the file manually everytime a new city gets added/removed.
   Also its generally not advisable to use FileBasedSpellChecker in
   general.
2. I also need to make the suggestions searchable as well, that means
   currently I am accessing the doc returned in

   ```
   "responseHeader":{"response":{"docs":[<some-format>]}}
   ```

   to search for results in that city, but now I want the suggestor to
   return the results in the same `<some-format>` instead of just
   string results, in order to get it integrated with UI properly.
3. One minor change requested is to sort the suggestions in ascending
   order of edit/levenshtein distance. This is not a hard requirement
   and can be negotiated with.

**edit**
 My solrconfig looks like this:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
       <str name="df">searchfield</str>
       <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">file</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">5</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
     </lst>
     <arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
     </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

and

```
  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
        <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_ngram</str>
        <lst name="spellchecker">
                <str name="name">file</str>
                <str name="classname">solr.FileBasedSpellChecker</str>
                <str name="sourceLocation">spellings.txt</str>
                <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
        </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

schema looks like this:

```
 <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="latlng" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="citycode" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="country" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="searchscore" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="searchfield" type="text_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true"  omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />
<defaultSearchFieldsearchfield</defaultSearchField>
        <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
        <copyField source="name" dest="searchfield"/>
```

Comment: What is the field type of the field you have your cities in? Can it be that you're seeing a stemmed/processed version of the city name? Indexing the city name by itself to a separate field and then using that for suggestions might be better.

Comment: I am indexing it on searchfield whose schema entry looks like this

`<field name="searchfield" type="text_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true"  omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" />`

Comment: A ngram field will generate loads of tokens, so my guess is that you're seeing suggestions based on partial tokens from that field. Use a regular stringfield or a keywordtokenized field to get exact suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't worked. with following solrconfig change`<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">string</str><str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">string</str> <lst name="spellchecker"><str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str><str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str><str name="field">name</str><str name="buildOnCommit">true</str><str name="distanceMeasure">org.apache.lucene.search.spell.LevensteinDistance</str></lst></searchComponent>`

Comment: Have decided to go with FileBasedSpellChecker. I might try to use FileDictionaryFactory for getting answers for the second question.